# Update another database from a dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I have trying to update 2 databases on my SQL Server using C# and datasets from one data connection. 
Is this possible?

In my `DataTable` I reference both the database and the table in the same query.

```
select * from Database2.dbo.Table
```

I click on the advanced options and set the `Generate Insert, Update and Delete` statements.

Everything looks fine on the wizard results page, but when I go again to the advanced options screen , the checkbox for `Generate Insert, Update and Delete` statements is not set.

Is there any way to get around this or do I need to use 2 data connections?

Comment: I believe it is best practice that C# application should update one database, and database stored procedure or trigger or database job should update the secondary database if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update both databases from your C# application, you have to create two separate connection for them.

I believe it is best practice that C# application should update one database, and database stored procedure or trigger or database job should update the secondary database if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use more than one database connection for a single dataset. You must create multiple datasets for each database.